# Cant find phpmyadmin.conf for Allow IP to access

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Im using 
Server version: 5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

I try to connect db with

```
var mysql_crawl = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'xxxx',
    database: 'db_xx'
});
```

Im goint to allow ip to access but i cant find

```
/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
```

Its no `conf.d` folder

Comment: If your ever stuck finding a file use `sudo find / -name phpmyadmin.conf`

Comment: I find `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf` but cant use for allow IP

Comment: Are you trying to give access to the mysql database from remote users?  If so - then it's the mysqld.cnf in /etc/mysql/mysq.conf.d

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin's configuration is not related to what you are attempting. If your MySQL server is running on the same machine as where you run your program, try 'localhost' for the 'host' parameter.